# I want to make an article which I can reference to.

Tags: discussion

We are having a lot of questions on combinatorics which can be considered as a case of arranging balls in boxes. That would make a total of $6$ different cases and I would like to make an article to discuss these so that I can reference to in future. Is it acceptable to ask a question and then answer my own question?

Comment: @GrigoryM That does not answer my question what should I do. Someone has not yet asked a general question.

Comment: «I suggest we use this question as a list of the generalized questions *we create*.». See also [Coping with *abstract* duplicate questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1756/). Short version: yes, it is acceptable.

Comment: I think this would be a good topic for the [proposed math blog](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13422/a-community-blog-for-math-se).

Answer (score 3):

It is expressly permitted to answer your own question. That's why the asking-a-question form has a box for simultaneously posting an answer to the question.

If you do this you should link your question and answer from the list of generalizations of common questions mentioned above.